# Add delimiter to pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, string, rename

Hello Stack Community!!

I am here with a beginner question, I am new to python and trying to practice using functions to make my code cleaner.

I am trying to modify all of the column names in a df via for loop and append those new delimited column names to a list.  I am hoping I can then use that list to rename all the columns at once.

I know I could type this out and map it as a dictionary but there has to be a better way!

MY CODE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmKUt.png)

you can see the unsuccessful output.  Each column name should have a '_' to delimit the words.

any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried several things and feel as though I am missing something very simple.  I have struggled through the documentation and self learning resources I have.

For the sake of speed and trying to become more relevant in this community I figured I'd give stackoverflow a shot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issues are you are using a built-in name "list" as an arg and you never .split() on " " and finally you append the original name variable since you didn't reassign after .join().

You can use a list comprehension together with [.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and assign the return list to df.columns:

Fake Data:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"Foo Spam": [1, 2, 3], "Ham Eggs": [4, 5, 6]}
RAW_edu = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

To make your code work:

```
def add_delimiter(cols: list) -> list:
    d = "_"
    delimited_cols = []
    for name in cols:
        name = d.join(name.split(" "))
        delimited_cols.append(name)
    return delimited_cols


RAW_edu.columns = add_delimiter(cols=RAW_edu.columns)
print(RAW_edu)
```

Using a generator and list comp Code:

```
def add_delimiter(cols: list) -> list:
    return ["_".join(iter(x.split(" "))) for x in cols]


RAW_edu.columns = add_delimiter(cols=RAW_edu.columns)
print(RAW_edu)
```

Output:

```
   Foo_Spam  Ham_Eggs
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

Comment: This is excellent!  Thank you this did work.  

i was also able to use the .replace() method on a list of the column names.

Comment: Thanks this is very functional!  I was also able to get it to work by using .replace() instead of join.  

Then creating two lists: 1 of delimited column names 1 original column names.

I zipped these together to create a tuple and converted the tuple to a dictionary to use with the .rename() function.  

Your way is much cleaner.

Comment: yw please mark as resolved when you get a chance